# EasyCustomLabel in QGIS do not resize the labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, visualisation

I use EasyCustomLabel to move some labels, but if I try to change the dimensions of the chars I cannot view any changes, both in the work and in the printing sheets.

I use QGIS 2.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the *Attribute table* of the EasyCustomLabel layer to change the size of the fonts. Update the `lblSize` field:

[image: Attribute update]